# I want to scroll only 1 div element, but css overflow: auto doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0;}
ul {list-style: none;}

.work_page
{
    display: flex;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}

.btn_text
{
    display: flex;
    width: 50vw;
    height: 100vh;
    font-size: 5vw;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: grey;
}

.work
{
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

.btn_text ul
{
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

.personal
{
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.team_work
{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    width: 50vw;
    height: 200vh;
    background-color: blue;
}

.team_work div
{
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40vh;
    width: 15vw;
    height: 40vh;
    margin: 10vh 1vw;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}
```

```html
<div class="work_page">
        <div class="btn_text">
            <div class="work">work</div>
            <ul>
                <li class="team">team</li>
                <li class="personal">personal</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="team_work">
            <div data-aos="fade-up"
            data-aos-easing="linear"
            data-aos-duration="2000">work1</div>
            <div data-aos="fade-up"
            data-aos-easing="linear"
            data-aos-duration="2000">work2</div>
            <div data-aos="fade-up"
            data-aos-easing="linear"
            data-aos-duration="2000">work3</div>
            <div data-aos="fade-up"
            data-aos-easing="linear"
            data-aos-duration="2000">work4</div>
            <div data-aos="fade-up"
            data-aos-easing="linear"
            data-aos-duration="2000">work5</div>
            <div data-aos="fade-up"
            data-aos-easing="linear"
            data-aos-duration="2000">work6</div>
        </div>
```

Hi guys.. Here's my code please tell me why it doesn't work
I want only scroll blue background div but It move together...
So result of googling that said add overflow-y: auto on div that you want scroll. then I added property on .team_work div but It doesn't work... I spent 2 hours to fix it!!! Help me!

Answer (score 1):

I have set to team_work 100vh instead 200vh.

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0;}
ul {list-style: none;}



.work_page
{
    display: flex;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}

.btn_text
{
    display: flex;
    width: 50vw;
    height: 100vh;
    font-size: 5vw;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: grey;
}

.work
{
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

.btn_text ul
{
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

.personal
{
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.team_work
{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    width: 50vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: blue;
}

.team_work div
{
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40vh;
    width: 15vw;
    height: 40vh;
    margin: 10vh 1vw;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="work_page">
        <div class="btn_text">
            <div class="work">work</div>
            <ul>
                <li class="team">team</li>
                <li class="personal">personal</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="team_work">
            <div data-aos="fade-up"
            data-aos-easing="linear"
            data-aos-duration="2000">work1</div>
            <div data-aos="fade-up"
            data-aos-easing="linear"
            data-aos-duration="2000">work2</div>
            <div data-aos="fade-up"
            data-aos-easing="linear"
            data-aos-duration="2000">work3</div>
            <div data-aos="fade-up"
            data-aos-easing="linear"
            data-aos-duration="2000">work4</div>
            <div data-aos="fade-up"
            data-aos-easing="linear"
            data-aos-duration="2000">work5</div>
            <div data-aos="fade-up"
            data-aos-easing="linear"
            data-aos-duration="2000">work6</div>
        </div>
  </div>
</body>
```